# Is there a way to configure a particular folder in Wamp to have an ipaddress

Tags: localhost, wamp, lan

I have already configured WAMP to work over LAN, by editing the virtual host. So all my system can access localhost/rise by typing in 192.168.1.14/rise.

Is there a method that I can use that can rewrite the URL form 192.168.1.14/rise to maybe 192.168.1.14 without typing in rise folder at the end, or at least a dedicated IP address.

The reason being, when I type the ip address over lan, I can still access the Server Configuration page, if I choose not to type /rise . I would like to access the same rise folder, by typing in a dedicated ipaddress.

I am using Windows 10, no Server. It is just a home network with 6 Computers

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO

Comment: To stop access to WAMPServer home page from other PC's change the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file to make localhost `Require local` and then the address `http://192.168.1.14/` will get rejected with a Cannot access this server message

Answer (score 0):

Whilst what you ask certainly is possible it is a questionable approach, there might be better solutions. However one thing after another:

1. for that you need your system to listen to multiple IP addresses at the same time, obviously. Also those addresses have to be known to all requesting clients. That is possible from a technical point of view, but depends a bit on your local network topology, most on how the addresses in your local network are managed. You probably will have to configure manual addresses for that, since no DHCP server will assign multiple addresses to a single requesting client. once that is done you can configure multiple hosts in your apache http server. Similar as you have already done. Actually address based virtual hosts were the traditional way of handling requests to separate services by a single (http) server. Take a look into the documentation of virtual hosts, the details are explained in there, obviously.
2. an alternative to that setup are name based virtual hosts. Those are the de facto standard these days for scenarios like yours. I would recommend that you use this approach instead of your original idea. For this you do *not* need to assign multiple IP addresses to your system. Instead you use the name resolution for different services ("folders" in your scenario), so you use host names like "folder1.local", "folder2.local". The trick is to get all those names resolved to a single IP address. This can be done either by entering those names into the "hosts" file of all requesting systems (`/etc/hosts` for unixoid syystems like Linux, there is something similar in MS-Windows). Or you setup a simple DNS server internally. Comes out the same. If that is done, then all that is left is to define a virtual host inside your apache http server for each of those folders, set a corresponding `ServerName` in its configuration and configure the correct `DocumentRoot the folder meant to be published. Again, the documentation is helpful for details and directives:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

Whatever approach you chose, you also need to take care of one additional aspect: the apache http server treats the first virtual host it finds in the configuration as "default host". Which means that one serves all requests that do *not* match any other host. I recommend to define a specific default host for that if you are concerned about people not being able to reach certain objects on your system. A specific host as a default host, which also is chosen if the system is requested by IP address instead of one of the host names explained in approach 2. And which you protect by additional means: either by blocking all requests that do not originate from the system itself or by configuring a password protection or similar.